# Using Int 21h ah=4eh/4fh: Program finds first file but not others

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

My program can not find the next file in the given directory. I'm including all my procedures in the event that they might be part of the problem. My program successfully finds the first file in the directory, but fails trying to find another one. (Yes, this program outputs nothing, it just finds file and open it, but the error could be seen on the debugger)

This is my code:

```
.model small
skaitymodydis   EQU 20          ;reading buffer size
.stack 1000h    
.data
zodis   db "hello", 0           ;searched word
dir db "P:\test\kazkas3", 0     ;directory path
fname db "index.html", 0        ;index file name
fhand dw ?                      ;index file handler
dhand dw ?                      ;other files handler
duom db "*.*", 0                ;searched file name
DTA db 128 (0)              
skbuf   db skaitymodydis dup (?);reading buffer
wrongg db "mistake"
eilutesnr dw 0001h              ;row number
naujaeilute db 13,10            ;new line
.code
start:
mov dx, @data
mov ds, dx

mov dx, offset DTA
mov ah, 1Ah
int 21h

mov dx, offset dir           ;DS:DX path-name
mov ah, 3Bh
int 21h
call kurtindex              ;creating index file procedure

call findfirst              ;finding first file procedure
call atidaryti              ;opening that first file
jmp skaityk                 ;start reading from file and working with its symbols
kitasfailas:
xor ax, ax
xor bx, bx
xor cx, cx
xor dx, dx
xor si, si 
xor di, di 

call findnext               ;finding next file; ERROR Place
call atidaryti              ;opening next files
skaityk:
mov bx, dhand               
call skaityti               ;reading symbols from file
call pilindex               ;filling index file procedure
call duomend                ;closing file procedure(not index)
jmp kitasfailas             ;trying to find another file
call indexend               ;closing index file
pabaiga:    
mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 0
int 21h

;***********************
;index failo pildymas
;***********************
proc pilindex
xor si, si
xor bx, bx
xor cx, cx
mov bx, fhand
mov cx, 7
mov dx, offset DTA+30  
mov ah, 40h
int 21h
mov bx, fhand
mov cx, 5
mov dx, offset zodis
mov ah, 40h
int 21h


mov cx, 2
mov bx, fhand
mov dx, offset naujaeilute
mov ah, 40h
int 21h
ret
pilindex endp
;***********************
;index failo sukurimo PROCEDURA
;***********************
proc kurtindex
mov cx, 0h
mov dx, offset fname
xor ax, ax
mov ah, 3Ch
int 21h
mov fhand, ax
ret
kurtindex endp

;***********************
;duomenu failo atidarymo PROCEDURA
;***********************
proc atidaryti
mov ah, 3Dh
mov al, 0
mov dx, offset DTA+30
int 21h
;jc wrong
mov dhand, ax
ret 
atidaryti endp
;***********************
;PROCEDURA nuskaitanti is failo
;***********************
proc skaityti
push cx
push dx
push bx 
mov bx, dhand
mov ah, 3Fh
mov cx, skaitymodydis
mov dx, offset skbuf
int 21h
jc skaitymoklaida

skaitytipab:
pop bx
pop dx
pop cx
ret

skaitymoklaida:
mov ax, 0
jmp skaitytipab
skaityti endp   

;***********************
;PROCEDURA find first
;***********************
proc findfirst

mov dx, offset duom
xor cx, cx
mov ah, 4Eh
int 21h
ret 
findfirst endp
;***********************
;PROCEDURA find next
;***********************
proc findnext
mov dx, offset duom
xor cx, cx
mov ah, 4Fh
int 21h
ret
findnext endp
;***********************
;duomenu failo uzdarymo PROCEDURA
;***********************
proc duomend
mov ah, 3Eh
mov bx, dhand
int 21h
ret
duomend endp
;***********************
;index failo uzdarymo PROCEDURA
;***********************
proc indexend
mov ah, 3Eh
mov bx, fhand
int 21h
 ret
indexend endp
end start
```

Comment: Don't you even **glimpse** briefly at the question you wrote? **So** many typos are certainly unnecessary.

Comment: @cad I'm not sure what you meant. It is too much information? I tried to include few parts, because maybe there is is problem with DTA when i'm doing certain moves.

Comment: This minimal amount of code is not enough to help. At least if you posted all the code then we might actually have a chance to see where things go wrong. Try creating a new program without all the overhead that demonstrates the issue. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: typos -> Typing mistakes like "can'f" instead of "can't". I just mean you could care more about the format of your question because badly looking questions tend to get downvoted rather than pretty ones.

Comment: @MichaelPetch My whole code is ~500 rows, and I have mentioned that i tried simply program and it finds all the files.

Comment: @cad Sorry for grammar, but I tried to do my best by formulating well looking but short question with details.

Comment: Reduce the code to something smaller. For example. Use fixed file names to search rather than taking command line arguments etc. You can reduce your 500 lines of code down to a bare minimum to demonstrate the issue. If you posted 500 lines of code, there is a whole lot better chance someone might be able to eyeball the issue. Posting the extremely small snippets with no context is useless. I recommend you step through your code using a debugger (Turbo debugger works quite well) to see where things go wrong.

Comment: I don't criticize your grammar - it's not perfect but we all can live with that. I mean *typing mistakes* and lack of code formatters etc.. Maybe I'm judging this too harshly but you could make your question way better looking and thus be better received.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm shorting my code for you. So you could help me, by the way should i edit this question or create new?

Comment: Edit your existing question.

Comment: If interrupt `21h` functions `4Eh` and `4Fh` worked in your small test program, but not in your bigger program, the fault must lie in that you expanded your program without testing its functioning step by step. So it's no use posting code that you know works. But note that function `4Fh` does not take any parameters, you provide them unnecessarily.

Comment: @cad added some code. ps i will delete these "up" comments after you will notice

Comment: Oh, yes I have forgot to mention. This program does nothing at the moment, because i deleted many content of the program. But it should open all files in the directory. Debugging it carry flag sets on the 4Fh command. This file looking for the files named any name "*.*" and should write content from files in the index. But as I mentioned earlier, it just opens them

Comment: In that case, there is no "next" file! There can only be a "next" file if your file spec contained a wildcard.

Comment: Actually, there should be "next" file, because I tried this program in many directories, so there is some problem in the code. @WeatherVane what do you mean wildcard?

Comment: @rkhb could you help me with this one? I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: As @MichaelPetch wrote: you will only find one file matching `"index.html"`, you need a wildcard such as `"*.html"`. BTW why do you not check the `C` flag on return from functions `4Eh` and `4Fh` which indicates success or failure?

Comment: @WeatherVane Um, i do not searching index.html at all, because I use "*.*" for my search (variable - "duom"). I check, if carry flag is on that means no files matched it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Looks like he intention is to use the `*.*` query to open all the files in a directory and then output information into `index.html` (I wasn't sure at first). On a side note `index.html` is not an 8.3 file name (extensions can only be 3 characters)

Comment: @MichaelPetch yeah, i saw that it creates .htm file for me. Yes, my intention is to find every file and output information to index.html. So, maybe you checked this program on a debugger do it works fine for you?

Comment: *Where* do you check the `C` flag returned? Not in the code you posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane   Using Turbo Debugger (DOS-BOX installed debugger)

Comment: I know your immediate problem is finding the *next* file, but how can you possibly know when you have found the *last* file (or even the *first* file) without checking the `C` flag as a program instruction? The code just ploughs blindly on.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have carryfkag jumper in the real program. It is just a part of it.

Comment: So after all, this isn't even your code? I am OUT of here.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you read it from the begining comments. Michael advised to shorten my real code into the problem one and repost it, I done it, and still having the same problem.

Comment: `DTA db 128 (0) ` you sure that is right? Seems to me you meant `DTA db 128 DUP (0) ` . I think you mean to create a buffer of 128 bytes filled with zeroes. I don't think you did that right

Comment: @MichaelPetch I do not blame you at all :D,  I tried to shorten the code until it has the actual problem. And finally, you found it. It was really dumb problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most obvious issue is related to how you define your DTA area:

```
DTA db 128 (0)
```

It appears that this creates a single byte initialized with 128+(0)=128. I think you intended to create a buffer of 128 bytes zero filled. You should have used:

```
DTA db 128 DUP(0)
```

This is likely causing the interrupt routines using DTA to clobber your data area causing things to work incorrectly.